# Midpoints of "hyperquadrilaterals" are vertices of...?

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, quadrilateral

It is written in this book I am reading that midpoints of a quadrilateral are vertices of a parallelogram.

What about bigger dimensions? Do "hyperquadrilaterals" also share that property? If not all of them, is there some infinite (in the sense that we count all similar figures as one figure)) subset of the set of "hyperquadrilaterals" that preserves this fact from two dimensions?

Comment: What is your definition of *hyperquadrilateral*? If $A,B,C,D\in\mathbb{R}^n$, it is trivial that the midpoint of the segment joining $\frac{A+B}{2}$ with $\frac{C+D}{2}$ is also the midpoint of the segment joining $\frac{B+C}{2}$ with $\frac{A+D}{2}$.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio I think we need $2^n$ points to have a hyperquadrilateral in space of n dimensions, right?

Comment: Plus some other conditions.

Comment: The word tells that a quadrilateral is something with four (*quad-*) sides (*lat-*), but in $\mathbb{R}^n$ with $n\geq 3$ the definition of *hyper*quadrilateral has to be given. Otherwise, what are we talking about?

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio In three dimensions parallelepiped would be an example. How would you define it in n dimensions? I am thinking of one approach.

Comment: If I chosen wrong word, how to call them?

Comment: These are not parallelotopes either, right?